# How to search for images in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-volley, google-image-search

I have some `EditTexts` in my `Activity`.First text the for the `title`, second is for `author`.Now the user loose focus from the second edittext `ie author`.I want to get the images related to that content (title and author).So what I did, I concat the `title and author name` and make `HTTP request using Volley`.And I print that response.But the response is so unpredictable that I can not fetch the images from it.

```
try {
        String googleImageUrl = "http://images.google.com/images?q=";
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(title + " " + author, "utf-8");
        String url = googleImageUrl + query;
        Toast.makeText(context, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        post_des.setText("Response is: " + response);
                        Log.i("Show me something awesome dude", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                post_des.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the responce is like this:

```
Response is: <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="en-IN"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon"><title>something something - Google Search</title><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;z-index:998;right:0}.gbto #gbs{background:#fff}#gbx3,#gbx4{background-color:#2d2d2d;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -138px;background-repeat:repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;height:29px;_height:30px;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:990}#gbx3{left:0}#gbx4{right:0}#gbb{position:relative}#gbbw{left:0;position:absolute;top:30px;width:100%}.gbtcb{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}#gbz .gbtcb{right:0}#gbg .gbtcb{left:0}.gbxx{display:none........like wise
```

I was expecting to get a Html doc. 
So how to make a HTTP request for images with the content(title and author).

**Edit**
*In layman language*,

Suppose I am on images.google.com, and I typed in something in search bar, and make a search, now I want the data that Google return as the `Url of the images on that webpage`(I am doing all this in backend not showing it to the user.)
I think it is now understandable :)

Comment: It is better to use a well documented JSON/XML API instead.

Comment: your api should return title,author and url of the image all these should be in json format

Comment: I have never used this but perhaps [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) is what your are looking for.

Comment: your app purpose is to let user search for specfic content(title,auther,image) or what?what is the back-end tech you used?

Comment: title,author should send to select the url of images related to it...your web services shoud response with json of these urls....your problem is code that make request to get back these images am i correct??

Comment: i will post volley code do the trick but the response should be json format ..ok??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165177/discussion-between-tigo2018-and-meditat).

Comment: Downvoting without comment does not work.Tell me the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got `html` but of the whole search page. You can retrieve pictures' urls with  [css selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J1Eq.png) and [JSOUP library][2] (easy to use). Just go to Chrome browser and then choose Settings - More tools - Developer tools. Then click the right mouse button on a picture and choose `inspect` and you'll see which container is for the pictures and what div contains src url of the images and then you right click this div and choose `copy css selector`. Then work with the library.

But be aware, it's not practical cause if they change the page html your code will beak. You better use specific api for this purpose, like Google Custom Search API as it was suggested in comments above.

To put image into UI you need to get its url address and then you can use `Glide` or `Picasso` or even `Volley`

```
// Retrieves an image with Volley specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

Here is CSS selector for all images on the google search page `img.rg_ic`. Using `Jsoup` and this selector you'll get access to all the image tags on the page

`Jsoup` example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(your link string).get();
Elements imgs = doc.select("img");//the selector
for (Element img : imgs) {
  //add img urls to String array and then use to get imgs with them
  String s = img.attr("src");
  arr.add(s);
}
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

**EDIT2 :**

Your code with changes:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textView;
String googleImageUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1366&bih=675&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=qFSJWsuTNc-wzwKFrZHoCw&q=";
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
String url;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("someething" , "something");
            getImages("https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1366&bih=675&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=qFSJWsuTNc-wzwKFrZHoCw&q=somethingsomething");
        }
    });
}

private void getImages(String url) {
    Document doc = null;
    try{
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements imgs = doc.select("img");
    System.out.println("Damn images"+imgs);
    for (Element img : imgs){
        Log.d("image-src", img.attr("data-src"));//changed `src` to `data-src`
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Yes! I have been searching for GoogleImages API, but manage to find GogoleCustomSearch API.But I have been wondering how to use it, for a couple of days.I have read the docs section.but maybe I'll manage that.

Comment: And the second thing I am not  getting the HTML doc,it is something else(view-source:https://www.google.co.in/search?q=something+something&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN784IN784&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2_Ye_w67ZAhUGXlMKHV-LAOsQ_AUICygC&biw=1366&bih=675).If I find something (Like the images tag)I will definitely solve my problem.

Comment: Man, you're really getting Html, trust me!) the first tag is <!doctype html> in the response but of the SEARCH page so it starts with headers and style and down there there are img tags but to parse it use JSOUP , I inspected the page you provided and edited the answer to give you css selector for all the img tags so when you parse html you'll get an array of img tags. See into jsoup more and how to parse html –

Comment: No @Rainmaker! nothing is happening. I am adding what I have tried with your code as EDIT in my question.

Comment: 1. Your url is wrong. Just try to go to that link in browser and you will see that it doesn't work. 2. try to use "img" sccselector. 3. I updated my answer, check it out

Comment: I take the link from the browser. My update shows that it works and  answers how to get images but there you have another problem, you need to format your link correctly and there's a way to do it but it should be answered in another thread as it's offtopic for this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165357/discussion-between-meditat-and-rainmaker).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a List of google search images using Jsoup .،. see official site here https://jsoup.org/

```
/**
 * Extract images from google as ArrayList.
 *
 * @param searchQuery is the string to search for
 * @return returnedURLS is the List of urls
 */
private List<String> extractImagesFromGoogle(String searchQuery) throws IOException {

    final String encodedSearchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8") + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUpP35yNXiAhU1BGMBHdDeBAgQ_AUIECgB";

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(encodedSearchUrl).get();
    String siteResponse = document.toString();

    List<String> returnedURLS = new ArrayList<String>();
    // parse the object and query the values (the urls) for specific keys ("ou")
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"ou\":\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(siteResponse);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        returnedURLS.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    return returnedURLS;
}

    // Test it now:
    List<String> retrievedURLS = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        retrievedURLS = extractImagesFromGoogle("pyramids");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(">> List Size: " + retrievedURLS.size());
    System.out.println(">> List of images urls: " + retrievedURLS);
```